# Angular - create a dynamic template for ng-repeat over different objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Suppose I have an array of objects. I need to create dynamically a table using `ng-repeat`. The thing is, I don't want to hardcode every property of the object to the `html`. I created an array which contain the relevant keys to the current object (the input can sometimes be different). How can I create `ng-repeat` which will run over each object of the data array and printing each property of the `keys` array I created earlier?
`xlsxTableProps` is an array with strings which are keys of every object inside `parsedXslxData` array of objects.

This is how I create the keys for the input (which again, can be different each time)
JS:

```
    Object.keys(this.parsedXslxData[0]).forEach(key => {
        this.xlsxTableProps.push(key)
      });
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col" ng-repeat="header in $ctrl.xlsxTableProps">{{header}}</th>                        
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.parsedXslxData">
        <td>{{$index}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="tableItem in $ctrl.xlsxTableProps"></td>
        <td>{{item[{{tableItem}}]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: problem is `{{item[{{tableItem}}]}}` might contain value for some and might not for others, right?

Comment: No, each data array is built the same. Once in a while it can be different, but every time this array will have the same structured objects

Comment: Ah I see the problem is with syntax, try simply `{{item[tableItem]}}`

Comment: it prints the table but does not fill it with data, I think it does not know whats the `[tableItem]` inside

Comment: My bad, it works flawlessly. Post a your answer and I'll select it as the right answer. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with your syntax here `{{item[{{tableItem}}]}}`, no need to use extra pair of brackets. Simply use `{{item[tableItem]}}`.